# How to force order in garbage collection in Python?

Tags: python, garbage-collection

In Python, I do not understand the order in the garbage collection.

Let's take an example with two objects: a context and a task. The task keeps a reference to the context. I thought the task would have been deleted first, but I was wrong.

You can see this with the following code:

```py
import gc

class Context:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ptr = 2

    def __del__(self):
        print("remove context (ctx refs: %d)" % len(gc.get_referrers(self)))

class Task:
    def __init__(self, ctx):
        self.ctx = ctx

    def __del__(self):
        print(self.ctx.ptr)
        print("remove task (ctx refs: %d)" % len(gc.get_referrers(self.ctx)))

ctx = Context()
t1 = Task(ctx)
t2 = Task(ctx)
print("ctx refs: %d" % len(gc.get_referrers(ctx)))
```

that gives this output:

```
ctx refs: 3
remove context (ctx refs: 2)
2
remove task (ctx refs: 0)
2
remove task (ctx refs: 0)
```

Why does the reference not force garbage collection of the task first? How can I force garbage collection of the context first?

How to explain the number of references?

Comment: Your code sample is not complete, because you did not show how you actually delete the objects.

Comment: Also, I don't believe your example necessarily has anything to do with garbage collection--the garbage collector is not responsible for deleting objects when their reference counts go to zero--that just happens automatically.  Where the garbage collector comes in is when there are reference *cycles*, such that some objects' reference counts can never go down to zero (hence they become garbage).  The reason `gc.get_referrers()` works is that most (though not all) objects are *tracked* by the garbage collector in case they should become part of a reference cycle.

Comment: Objects are freed when program exits. It is that I want to control.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.  How did you get the above output?  It's not clear; I don't see how you would make the `Context` object's `__del__` occur before both `Task`s are deleted.  Please post the rest of your code.  More generally, what is it that you're actually trying to accomplish?  Trying to fine-grain control how objects are freed in Python is probably an indication that you're not going about things the best way, as there is rarely any reason to do this.

Comment: Nevermind; I think I see what you're saying.  You mean this is the output you get when you exit the interpreter.  That said, I don't think you can easily control this; certainly not from the pure Python level. The exact order the interpreter does things while shutting down is complicated and difficult to control for.  It will tend to just forcibly set reference counts to zero and things like that.  This is partly why `__del__` is dangerous--you can assume when it's being called that the rest of the module the object is in is in a stable state.

Comment: I want `task` to be freed before `context` because in my functions I have C code from a library that is called and that needs calls in this order.

Comment: I think, in that case, it's important for you to provide more context (pun not intended) about this C code and how you're using it, why the free order matters.  This is not something you should be doing at the Python level, most likely.

Comment: My python code is a binding for the C code (I have no control on it). I can find a solution to avoid my problem but it is far less elegant. The goal of my question is to have a specific answer on the sub problem but not on my global situation. And of course, I would like to understand the mechanisms.

Comment: Since you do not clear references, the reference counts are non-zero, hence prevent count-based freeing while a tracing garbage collector would consider the entire object graph unreachable, hence, garbage. Within such garbage, there is no ordering relationship.

Comment: Yes, but your bindings are not written in Python but in C.  I think you'll need to be more specific about what the exact problem is before someone can help you find a workable solution.  Instead you've just decided what you think is the solution, but chances are there's a more viable solution. It just can't be suggested without more specific details.

Comment: Did you find a good solution to this problem? I have the same (wrapping a c library requiring specific order of cleanup)

Comment: @viblo Not really, nothing clean.